# python Logic mixup with krakenapi

Tags: python-3.x, kraken.com

Can anyone see the mistake in code

```
def add_kraken_order():

        url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder'
        key = 'PuwrA+0sssssssssNOTREALsssssssssssssssssq5qj'
        secret = 'NVZh7FlQBpssNOTREALssssssssssKBwq4CYSSIjspXR6XGg=='
        pair = 'XXBTZEUR'
        buysell = 'buy'
        ordertype = 'limit'
        volume = '1'
        orderinfo = ('AddOrder', {'pair': pair,'type' : buysell,
                             'ordertype' : ordertype, 'volume' : volume,})



        market='https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder'
        rr=request.post.market(orderinfo)
```

Comment: What kind of mistake? What makes you think there's a mistake? Are you looking for a syntax thing or a logic thing? Be specific - help us help you

Comment: Thinking the mistake is because of orderinfo, Probably best if I look on google for an example then go from there. Thanks for your interest Mr Avery